# DLNA support for iOS video app

Tags: ios, dlna

I am developing an video player app on iOS and I am now thinking about how to support DLNA so that my app can mirror its online video to the TV with some DLNA-supported device.

Notice that the online video is playing on my app via WIFI or cellular network and I could switch it to be played on TV and my app becomes a remote control and a server to the TV.

Which framework should I use?

I already know `Cyberlink` and `PlatinumKit`.

Comment: So whats up with `Cyberlink` and `PlatinumKit`? Or you looking for opinions?

Comment: @AdilSoomro, yes I am looking for some advise. Which one of those is better for my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on DLNA with iOS and Android device. I did not used the `Cyberlink` or `PlatinumKit`. I learned how it works and write with swift and java.

Here is my blog about the subject, if you only want the part of DLNA to find DLNA device and stream the video to the device, then control events like play, pause and seek. You could find all the material you need here.

https://eliyar.biz/DLNA_with_iOS_Android/

Comment: The link is in Simplified Chinese. I don't think most audience can understand.